# Automation Activity Fail - Auto Start Again?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

If any activity fails in automation studio, is there a way to automatically retry failed activity again after certain time, or retry again if fails?

Comment: What type of activity failure is occuring?  Would running the remaining steps of the automation be  the appropriate action for the failure or would the issue need to be troubleshot and corrected?

Comment: Yes, I can run the remaining steps or if activity fails at first step then I can manually run it. Which is actually I am doing right now. Usually it's not a failure which require troubleshot, I don't know why it happens but when I manually run the same activity it does not throw any error.

Comment: Maybe try this, add a step to your automation to update a DE when the process completes successfully.  Then schedule a copy of the automation to run later in the day, add a validation step to the beginning to only complete the steps if the DE in the 1st automation was updated.

Answer (score 2):

For out of the box your only choices are to wait for the next scheduled run/trigger or to manually 'Run Once' when you get the error notification email.

You are able to build something on your own (either via API or if hosted on SFMC, via SSJS) to check automation run status or try/catch script to run the automation, etc. to implement error handling and retrying. But keep in mind this would all be custom development and would likely require either a separate automation itself (Cloudpage and/or SSJS Script activity) or to be hosted and run on a 3rd party server.

Answer (score 0):

If is will start again on schedule ( if it is a scheduled automation) or when a file matching the trigger is dropped on the ftp server (if it is a file drop automation)

Comment: It's schedule base and it run one time every day. So if it fails today then now it will run tomorrow but with the new records.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add more details, So there are two activities in this automation. One is Data filter and other one is email. Automation run every day at specific time update data filter and then trigger an email if more than 0 records found.